# Virtualization on win 10

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, bios

I enabled my virtualization on windows 10 in the BIOS  setting and tried to power a linux o/s on the virtual machine and I end up with this error;

> This virtual machine is configured for 64-bit guest operating systems.
>   However, 64-bit operation is not possible.
>
> This host does not support Intel VT-x.
>
> For more detailed information, see http://vmware.com/info?id=152.

So i restart my system to check the bios setting and found out that the virtualization I enabled has already being disabled by the computer I tried severally same result and I have checked HP support for bios a update there was non for the model I am using

> the latest for my hp model is 2013 update F.37 and it is the version I
>   am running

I even formatted my system still same result  I am using a **hp pavillion g6**

Is there anything I can do to run make my bios setting STAY ENABLED  and if not is there any workaround the BIOS setting .??

Comment: I have to ask the obvious, when you leave the BIOS are you "save and exiting" (usually F10)?

Answer (score 0):

I bet you have Hyper-V installed, Microsoft Hyper-V takes exclusive control over Intel VT-x technology at startup, so other VM software is unable to use VT-x.

Check if you have Hyper-V enabled:

- Open the Add / Remove programs dialog, click Add / Remove features on the left.
- Find the Hyper-V add-in and un-check it.